# What's the proper way to handle concurrency exceptions in EventStore?

Tags: nservicebus, cqrs, neventstore, commondomain

Using JOliver EventStore 3.0 and reciving commands from NServiceBus, what's the proper way to handle concurrency exceptions?  If I have more than one worker thread, this could be a common occurance.

**Option 1**

```
try
{
    // store the event
    ...
}
catch (ConcurrencyException)
{
    _bus.HandleCurrentMessageLater();
}
```

**Option 2**

Let it throw back to NServiceBus and get retried with the MsMqTransportConfig.MaxRetries option from the config.

**Option 3**

Something I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compare the uncommitted events with the committed events and see if they actually conflict (according to your business rules) - if there's no conflicts then you can allow the events to be persisted, otherwise re-throw.

Generally though I just let it throw and have NServiceBus retry.

Comment: Is this something the command handler can retry if it is responsible for saving to the event store? Or should the entire command handle throw and reverse the transaction??